# Why cwRsync doesn't work on Windows?

Tags: windows, rsync, cwrsync

I'm trying to run rsync on Windows with the cwrsync port.

I'm issuing the following command (note that this is just a dry run):

```
rsync -nPaAz foouser@webxx.example.com:/home/foobar/webapps/barbaz/ C:\\mybackupfolder\
```

but I get the following error

```
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1148) [Receiver=3.0.8]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 23):

For the destination try using:

```
/cygdrive/c/mybackupfolder/
```

Note that a colon tells rsync that the location is remote.

Comment: Gotcha about the colon! But it doesn't seem to help. Tried this other version (%CD% is an env variable pointing to the current dir) too but still failing:

rsync -nPaAz foouser@webxx.example.com:/home/foobar/webapps/barbaz/ %CD%

Comment: what about changing to the destination directory and then just use "." for the destination?

Comment: This actually works for me. You can just prepend /cygdrive/ before any windows drive. I installed rsync through Chocolatey (therefore cygwin based).

Answer (score 8):

**My environment:  Windows 10, in powershell.  Solution also worked in a DOS prompt.**

The problem is caused by the `:` after the drive letters, which makes it look like a hostname specification.  You have to use an alternative notation.

I was using **rsync** installed via **Chocolatey**, so no cygwin drives.

Windows 10 lets me do this on powershell:

```
dir //localhost/C$
```

so, this command, run in a Windows 10 powershell, worked just fine for me, after running into same exact problem.

```
rsync -av //localhost/d$/home/work/fb460.winbup/src //localhost/d$/home/work/fb460.winbup/tgt
```

Comment: Note this doesn't work or at least I couldn't make it work for ext2fsd drives. Your experience might differ. However as I wanted to copy from ext2 to ntfs I just changed to the ext2 drive and ran `rsync -a some/path //localhost/c$/some/path`

Comment: I also installed via Chocolatey. This worked well for me! NTFS to NTFS.

Answer (score 5):

Got here from a similar problem with rsync for Windows.

Instead of using the path, just make a .bat file that uses `CD C:\whereto\` then in the rsync command just use `.` as the directory to save to.

Example (something.bat):

```
@echo off  
cd C:\mybackupfolder\  
rsync -nPaAz foouser@webxx.example.com:/home/foobar/webapps/barbaz/ .
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 rsync -nPaAz foouser@webxx.example.com:/home/foobar/webapps/barbaz/ C:/mybackupfolder/
```

Comment: This does not work as expected for me.

Comment: @EmreYazici What did you expect?

Comment: @Marki Whatever the expectation, that was nine years ago :)